Science fiction story about settling a planet with Adam and Eve
I read the story in a science fiction anthology in the early 80s. Two human forms, one male and one female were put on a planet by an advanced technology starship. A plot of the planet was made habitable for them by the technology of the starship. They initially could not stand each other but eventually mated, and their children populated the planet.

This is a very common plot, as per https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AdamAndEvePlot

There's "First Person Singular" by Eric Frank Russell. People from a planet called Dis set up colonies; a man is selected, and several females have the choice of whether to stay or not. (Only one can stay-it's not a harem) A redhead decides to stay. The colony initially goes well, but the planet is geophysically unsound; and they have to abandon the site. The last lines include "they left Para-Dis" and "this planet we call Terra".

"First Person Singular" it is, thank you so much. I remember it now, it was in an anthology volume called "Creations", edited by Isaac Asimov. Again, many many thanks

OP identified this in a comment as First Person Singular by Eric Frank Russell , which they read in the anthology Creations - the Quest for Origins in Story and Science, written/edited by Isaac Asimov.

Selected Granor Edham will be left on the newly surveyed planet by himself for five years in order to assess its suitability for colonisation.


Is this "Created He Them" by Alice Eleanor Jones? It's not a perfect match by any means, but the two protagonists do dislike each other.

Because by some twist of providence, or radiation, or genes, we
are among the tiny percentage of the people in this world who can
have normal children. We hate each other, but we breed true.

It's been published a few times. If it is your story, you probably read it in The Best from Fantasy and Science Fiction, Fifth Series, edited by Anthony Boucher.

I guess there are 10,000 stories about couples that dislike each other, and in a way they are all partial matches, but I believe the OP is looking for a story about space colonization.
